# Parser shift/reduce reduce/reduce conflicts

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

I'm given a parser written in `Lex` and `Yacc` which happens to be ambiguous and incomplete. When compiling, I get several shift/reduce and reduce/reduce conflicts. I cannot seem to find anything online that helps me understand what this really means and what needs to be done to fix it. I'm hoping someone here can help clear things up for me.

The parser:

```
%{
  #include <stdio.h>
  int yylex();
%}

%token ID INT_CONST REAL_CONST LPAREN RPAREN INT REAL VOID COMMA LCBRAC RCBRAC ASSIGN      SEMICOLON IF ELSE ADD RETURN SUBT MULT DIV FOR UNTIL 

%%                   /* beginning of rules section */

program : functionDeclarationS; 
functionDeclarationS : functionDeclaration | functionDeclaration functionDeclarationS;
functionDeclaration : typeSpecifier ID  LPAREN params RPAREN functionBody;
typeSpecifier : INT | VOID;
params : paramList | VOID;
paramList : param COMMA paramList | param;
param : typeSpecifier ID;
functionBody : LCBRAC localDeclarations statementS RCBRAC;
localDeclarations : varDeclarations SEMICOLON localDeclarations | ;
varDeclarations : INT varList;
varList : ID | ID COMMA varList;
statementS : statement statementS | ;
statement : assignment SEMICOLON | expression  SEMICOLON | ifStmt | return SEMICOLON;
assignment : ID ASSIGN expression;
expression : expression ADD expression | LPAREN expression RPAREN | expression;
expression : integer | real | ID | functionCall;
integer : sign INT_CONST;
real : sign REAL_CONST;
sign : ADD | SUBT| ;
functionCall : ID LPAREN argumentsList RPAREN;
argumentsList : expression | expression COMMA argumentsList | ;
ifStmt : IF LPAREN expression RPAREN block;
block : LCBRAC statementS RCBRAC;
return : RETURN expression ;

%%
int main()
{
  return(yyparse());
}

yyerror(s)
char *s;
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",s);
}

int yywrap()
{
  return(1);
}
```

The conflicts and warning messages:

conflicts: `11 shift/reduce`, `7 reduce/reduce`
**`parser.y:30.17-26:`** *warning*: rule useless in parser due to *conflicts: argumentsList: expression*
`**parser.y:33.10-26:**` *warning*: rule useless in parser due to *conflicts: return: RETURN expression*

Comment: Use the `-v` flag to yacc to produce a y.output file detailing all the states and the conflicts...

Comment: The [wikipedia page on shift-reduce parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift-reduce_parser) has lots of useful information and links for understanding LR parsing states and conflicts in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule `expression: expression` is meaningingless and makes the grammar ambiguous, and also results in a parser with an infinite loop, since an argumentList will try to expand it infinitely (this is why you get the message about `argumentsList: expression` being useless -- it is superceded by `expression: expression` so can never be reduced.)